# Make a JavaScript button print a value

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys I am trying to create a JavaScipt function that when called will print the value created by the claclBMI() function. I feel that having the first function do the calculations for the BMI is correct. Is there anyway to make the button print the result of the calcBMI function?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Body Mass Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="80%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Weight in Pounds</th>
    <th>Height in Inches</th>
    <th>Body Mass Index</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="box1" oninput="number" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input id="box2" oninput="number" type="text" /></td>
    <td><button onclick="printBMI()">Calculate BMI</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p id="calcBMI"></p>
<script>
 function calcBMI() 
{
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var BMI = document.getElementById('BMI'); 
  var myResult = (myBox1 * 703) / (myBox2 * myBox2);
  BMI.value = "parseInt(myResult)";
}
 function printBMI() 
{
    document.write (myResult);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you just replace `BMI.value = "parseInt(myResult)";` with `BMI.value = myResult;`? Also, your `onclick` for the button could just be `calcBMI()`.

Comment: `document.getElementById('BMI');` should be `document.getElementById('calcBMI');`

Comment: `BMI.value = ...` should be `BMI.textContent = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comments:

- `calcBMI` is not returning any value
- `document.getElementById('BMI');` finds nothing, since there is no element with id BMI
- `BMI.value` explodes, since BMI is undefined
- `parseInt(someStringWithDigits)` without quotes is a function, but what you have there is just a string, that does nothing
- You use `document.write(myResult)`, but the function printBMI can't see variables declared inside on the other function.

¿Is this some sort of assignment? If so, it would be nice to know what knowledge is expected for you to apply.

In order to solve some of your issues:

- `document.getElementById('box1');` will give you the first input
- `calcBMI` should return the value, unless you have a good reason to assign the result somewhere else, but from my perspective, it seems better to just return the value and make no other collateral effects.
- Once you do that, `document.write(calcBMI())` will erase everithing from your page and put the result instead. You probably want to put the result somewhere specific, but I suppose it's a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parseInt() before trying to run calculations on them, if they are retrieved as a string:

```
function calcBMI() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    var BMI = document.getElementById('BMI');   
    var myResult = (parseInt(myBox1) * 703) / (parseInt(myBox2) * parseInt(myBox2));
    BMI.value = myResult;
}
```

Also if you want the result to be on the text of the button it would be:

```
BMI.innerHTML = myResult;
```

Also, when you call the printBMI() function document.write() erases everything on the page, I think, and replaces it with your value.